# How do I match a group of observations with a dyad?

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation, matching

Say I have a data frame with a list of names and the companies they have as clients:

```
name <- c("Anne", "Anne", "Mary", "Mary", "Mary", "Joe", "Joe", "Joe", "David", "David", "David", "David", "David")
company <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H")

df1 <- data.frame(name, company)
```

Then I have a second data frame where I have companies who are working together on projects:

```
company1 <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H")
company2 <- c("B", "C", "E", "E", "G", "A", "B", "C")

df2 <- data.frame(company1, company2)
```

My preferred outcome would be something like this:

```
  name      A     B     C     D     E     F     G     No of sets
1 Anne      1     1     0     0     0     0     0     1
2 David     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1
3 Joe       1     1     1     0     0     0     0     2
4 Mary      0     0     1     1     1     0     0     1
```

So this counts the number of "sets" that match the sets in df2. For example, Anne has A and B with 1s, and it matches row 1 in df2. Joe has A, B, C, and both A and B and B and C are rows in df2, thus Joe's row has two matches.

Comment: Hi @hy9fesh, would you please be more specific about what you are trying to accomplish? Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for `table(df2[,1], df2[,2])`?

Comment: "I'm thinking of several ways of manipulating the data" is not a clear goal that we can help with.

Comment: Can you show your expected output ? As mentioned by others your question is not very clear.

Comment: Sorry everyone. I added my expected outcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might work for you. Let me know. It doesn't match your expected result because you didn't include `H`, which I presumed to be a typo? Likewise, should Mary's `No_of_sets` also equal 2?

```
# Tabulate the frequency of name x company combinations
r <- as.data.frame.matrix(table(df1$name, df1$company))
r
#>       A B C D E F G H
#> Anne  1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
#> David 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1
#> Joe   1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
#> Mary  0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0

# Get "sets" of companies working together
s <- paste(df2$company1, df2$company2)
s
#> [1] "A B" "B C" "C E" "D E" "E G" "F A" "G B" "H C"

# Get all potential company sets associated with each name
m <- apply(r, MARGIN = 1, FUN = function(x) combn(names(which(x==1)), 2))

# Intersect sets of companies potentially working together (m) with
# companies actually working together (df2)
# (You could use a nested apply here, but I thought that it
# would be too opaque. Looping is a little more clear.)
for(name in rownames(r)){
  pairs <- m[[name]]
  ppairs <- apply(pairs, 2, paste0, collapse = " ")
  r[which(rownames(r)==name),"No_of_sets"] <- length(intersect(ppairs, s))
}
r
#>       A B C D E F G H No_of_sets
#> Anne  1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0          1
#> David 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1          2
#> Joe   1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0          2
#> Mary  0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0          2

Created on 2021-10-19 by the reprex package (v2.0.1)
```

Edit: Let's say there's a chance that one name isn't working with more than one company. In that case, you'd need to add a conditional to account for this in both steps. First, new data... notice that the name "Solo" is only working with one company.

```
r
#>       A B C D E F G H
#> Anne  1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
#> David 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1
#> Joe   1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
#> Mary  0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0
#> Solo  1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

m <- apply(r, MARGIN = 1, FUN = function(x)
  if(length(names(which(x==1)))>1) {
    combn(names(which(x==1)), 2)
  } else names(which(x==1))
)
m
#> $Anne
#>      [,1]
#> [1,] "A" 
#> [2,] "B" 
#> 
#> $David
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
#> [1,] "D"  "D"  "D"  "D"  "E"  "E"  "E"  "F"  "F"  "G"  
#> [2,] "E"  "F"  "G"  "H"  "F"  "G"  "H"  "G"  "H"  "H"  
#> 
#> $Joe
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,] "A"  "A"  "B" 
#> [2,] "B"  "C"  "C" 
#> 
#> $Mary
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,] "C"  "C"  "D" 
#> [2,] "D"  "E"  "E" 
#> 
#> $Solo
#> [1] "A"
for(name in rownames(r)){
  pairs <- m[[name]]
  if(length(pairs)>1){
    ppairs <- apply(pairs, 2, paste0, collapse = " ")
  } else ppairs <- pairs
  r[which(rownames(r)==name),"No_of_sets"] <- length(intersect(ppairs, s))
}
r
#>       A B C D E F G H No_of_sets
#> Anne  1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0          1
#> David 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1          2
#> Joe   1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0          2
#> Mary  0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0          2
#> Solo  1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0          0
```

Comment: This is really helpful, but what is going on here? `FUN = function(x) combn(names(which(x==1)), 2)`

Comment: "return all combinations of pairs of column names where row value is 1." MARGIN=1 does this one row at a time. Let me know if that doesn't make sense.

Comment: I'm getting the following error when I try to apply the `apply()` to a similar dataset: `Error in combn(names(which(x == 1)), 2) : n < m`

Comment: This suggests that there are <2 columns with values equal to 1.  Take a look at your frequency table `r`

Comment: I should rephrase. This suggests there's at least one name that has <2 column values equal to 1. Take a look at your `r`, is that true?

Comment: Yes. How do I account for 0 number of sets?

Comment: I added an edit to my answer. Let me know if it works.

Comment: It works! Thanks so much!